# How to read a PDF into byte array using Jackson Object Mapper

Tags: java, pdf, jackson, objectmapper

I am trying to get a PDF from a 3rd party API and then return it as an attachment from my API/Server. I normally return PDF documents using a byte array without an issue, however, I can not seem to figure out how to get the response from the 3rd party api into a byte array without getting a JSON Parse error from Jackson.

Here is the code that I am trying to use to get the PDF as a byte array from the 3rd party API:

```
    URI uri = URI.create(String.format(URL_INVOICE_PDF_TEMPLATE, getBaseUrl(), invoiceId));
    
    byte[] pdfBytes = null;

    try (CloseableHttpResponse res = get(uri)) 
    {
      pdfBytes = getMapper().readValue(res.getEntity().getContent(), byte[].class);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      if (e.getError().getHttpStatusCode() != 404)
        throw e;
    }
```

However, I keep getting a JsonParseException.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full stack trace.

Comment: Why do you need an `ObjectMapper` if you're just pulling it into a `byte[]`, which is the most basic and original representation anyway?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- you are correct, I was over thinking it. I just eneded up using IOUtils to convert the input stream into a byte []